# Getting values of two dynamic inputs in AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How I can get multiplying of two strings values (quantity and price) then get it in input of string netValue, where AJAX cs code as below:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        string brandName = "";
        string itemName = "";
        string itemId = "";
        string quantity = "";
        string price = "";
        string netValue = "";
```

then

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Clear();
```

HTML Dynamic Table body:

```
  string html = "";
            html += "<tr>";
            html += "<td class='style39'>";
            html += "<input type='textbox' value='" + brandName + "' Width='98px'></input>";
            html += "</td>";
            html += "<td class='style39'>";
            html += "<input type='textbox' value='" + itemId + "' Width='98px'></input>";
            html += "</td>";
            html += "<td class='style41'>";
            html += "<input type='textbox' value='" + itemName + "' Width='169px'></input>";
            html += "</td>";
            html += "<td class='style43'>";
            html += "<input type='textbox' value='" + quantity + "' Width='84px'></input>";
            html += "</td>";
            html += "<td class='style49'>";
            html += "<input type='textbox' value='" + price + "' Width='95px'></input>";
            html += "</td>";
            html += "<td class='style51'>";
            html += "<input type='textbox' value='" + netValue + "' Width='98px'>  </input>";
            html += "</td>";
            html += "</tr>";



        Response.Write(html);
        Response.End();
        Response.Flush();
    }
```

Comment: show what you tried/

Comment: Read about [`Event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: What's the relation of Event delegation URL with my question?

Comment: guradio:
I tried many method but it doesn't complete, because of above code depend on previous form, I need your experiences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it by:

```
decimal Result;

        Result = Convert.ToDecimal(string.IsNullOrEmpty(quantity) ? "0" : quantity) * Convert.ToDecimal(string.IsNullOrEmpty(price) ? "0" : price);

        netValue = Result.ToString();
```

But after row created and enter quantity value, there's no action defined to detect value entered in quantity input, **so is there any solution for that?**

Comment: But after row created and enter quantity value, there's no action defined to detect value entered in quantity input, so is there any solution for that?